# Delay measurement during ZeroMQ communication between Blender and LabVIEW

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, labview

I'm trying to communicate between LabVIEW and python using ZeroMQ socket library(PUB-SUB), both on the same local machine(OS-windows) and trying to measure the delay at the receiving end. Basically, I'm triggering the LabVIEW's(this is being the publisher) while loop every 1000 ms and reading the digital output on a channel of an oscilloscope. On the blender side, the logic tick rate (execution frequency of the python script) is 60 Hz, which means that the receive function in the python script is being executed every 16.67ms and then I was displaying the message as a digital output from LabVIEW using an Arduino(writing on a serial port only when we receive something from LabVIEW) on the second channel of the oscilloscope. I was supposed to see delay and jitter in microseconds but what I'm seeing is something completely random. Any suggestion or help would be much appreciated regarding getting the delay and jitter right.

Comment: Labview + python + ZeroMQ + whatever OS your running (Windows?) will not ever give you jitter as good as microseconds. You'd need something pretty bespoke, based on a hard RTOS like VxWorks.

Comment: yeah, I'm running everything on Windows. Does that mean the maximum jitter I can achieve with windows is its time resolution(i.e. 15.6 ms)?

Comment: The best jitter you can likely achieve with Windows as a foundation is probably going to be significantly worse that 15.6ms. For jitter down to microseconds, you're looking at something fairly bespoke, and definitely not LabVIEW, python, ZeroMQ and Windows.